# Alexa.NET check custom slot value is valid and if not, prompt user for correct slot value

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I am writing an Alexa skill using C# / Lambda / Alexa.NET

I have a custom slot list for systems the user can respond with. There are 3 valid slot values. The Lambda code at the moment uses the delegate directive to pass control of the conversation to Alexa to handle obtaining the system slot, as well as a couple of other slots. This is currently catered for here:

```
 // check the name to determine what you should do
                    if (intentRequest.Intent.Name.Equals("problemIntent"))
                    {
                        context.Logger.LogLine($"The specific intent I have created has been received");
                    }

                    context.Logger.LogLine($"Dialog state = {intentRequest.DialogState}");

                    if (intentRequest.DialogState != "COMPLETED")
                    {
                        response = ResponseBuilder.DialogDelegate(input.Session);
                    }
```

However, the user can respond with a system that isn't a valid part of the list, and Alexa will accept this, confirm and continue.

How do I validate the incoming slot value to determine that it isn't correct (isn't a valid slot value) and prompt the user for a correct value? I have a List of strings in my Lambda function to validate against, but how do I obtain the value of the provided slot in code? E.g. pseudo code would be:

if dialog state is not complete
check slot value provided against list. 
if valid, delegate back to ALexa to continue. 
if not valid, respond with speed saying 'I don't know what  is. Can you try another value? For example x,yz'